# Wicked pdf render_to_string to generate pdf wider than browser's viewport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Im using wicked pdf for generating pdf files from views, but I mentioned that wicked_pdf cant generate pdf wider, than my browser's viewport.
Is it possible to generate pdf with render_to_string from view, that wider than browser's viewport when filled with data?
p.s sorry for tautology.

Comment: `:orientation => 'Landscape'` ?

Comment: render_from_string ? what is that

Comment: @nithin, sorry, that was a typo, I meant render_to_string method.

Comment: I will try `:orientation => 'Landscape'`, but what if it would be wider, that landscape orientation?

Comment: Orientation should not affect the result as the wkhtmltopdf browser-side renders the page in a fixed viewport, thus affecting the layout either by scrollbars or responsivness BEFORE the result is "printed" to a PDF, probably with a `fit to page` option set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf [v0.12.0 added support](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for `--viewport-size` option that you could use to adjust the viewport to your liking.

Unfortunately WickedPdf doesn't seem to have upgraded to that version yet and does not allow you to specify viewport size.

At the moment your best option would be to patch WickedPdf yourself by adding `:viewport_size` to the allowed options somewhere in the [`parse_others` method](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L236) (don't forget documentation and README) and then make a pull-request.

Comment: Seems that `:orientation => 'Landscape'` solved the problem, but this is only a workaround, so yeah, this option definitly should be implemented in wicked_pdf gem, thx!

Comment: Do yo know whitch is the format of "viewport_size". Example: viewport_size: '1437×801' is this right?

Comment: sorry, I don't know it, but that would seem plausible.